# how do I check whether a text box that is dynamically created is populated with data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 10 rows of text boxes (4 columns)

If ALL 10 rows have been populated with data, I need to fire an event to do certain things.

I'm new to web development and I don't really understand how to reference an item on the HTML page that was dynamically generated by the code-behind. This is what it looks like in HTML:

```
<tr align="center">
 <td style="height: 85px">
    </td>
     <td align="center" style="width: 440px; height: 310px">
       <fieldset class="field1" style="text-align: center">
          <legend class="Eblegend" id="legendObligation2">
              <%=frameName%>
             </legend>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlTable" runat="server" Width="620px" Height="310px">
            </asp:Panel>
           </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code turns into an editable table (4 columns and 10 rows).

I need to check if all boxes have been filled so that I can enable a "next" button.

The problem is, I don't know how to reference these "cells" on the dynamically generated table so that i can say "if not null or empty, do this"

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: could you do something like this if youi're using asp:TextBox 
`foreach(var tbCtrl in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to access the values, you need to create the `TextBoxes` also in the case of a PostBack. This has to happen very early and the Ids of the controls need to be the same.

The following code shows a small sample that creates a TextBox dynamically and reads the value later on:

**ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateTextBox" runat="server" Text="Create TextBox" OnClick="btnCreateTextBox_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnPostBack" runat="server" Text="Do a postback" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected TextBox txt;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Any(x => x == "TextBox1"))
            CreateTextBox();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt != null)
            lbl.Text = "TextBox value is " + txt.Text;
        else
            lbl.Text = "No value in TextBox";
    }

    protected void btnCreateTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt == null)
        {
            CreateTextBox();
        }
    }

    private void CreateTextBox()
    {
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "TextBox1";
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

The important part is that the TextBox is created in `OnInit` with the same ID if there is a value in the PostBack data. Even if the TextBox is empty, the key of the TextBox (TextBox1 in the case of the sample) is present in the `AllKeys` collection.